# Does rand() ever return zero on OSX?

Tags: c, macos, random, probability

I have been running this code for almost ten hours with no love:

```
 while ( true ) {
     int r = rand();
     assert( r != 0 );
 }
```

I expect rand() to eventually roll a zero and thus trigger the assert.

Am I doing something wrong or does rand() never return zero?

Or have I not been waiting long enough to expect to see it?  I'm on 2012-vintage 2GHz i7.

Comment: you haven't initialized it with a seed (`srand`)  http://www.codingunit.com/c-reference-stdlib-h-function-rand-generate-a-random-number

Comment: @chiliNUT: It's not obligatory to seed the random number generator.

Comment: @chiliNUT `rand()` behaves as if `srand(1)` has been called, when there is no `srand( )`.

Comment: What is `RAND_MAX()`?   If it is large, it will take a long time.

Comment: @chux: It can't be larger than INT_MAX

Comment: The OS X libc is open source, btw.: [`rand()`](https://www.opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/Libc-1044.1.2/stdlib/FreeBSD/rand.c) and [`<stdlib.h>`](https://www.opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/Libc-1044.1.2/include/stdlib.h).

Comment: With glibc, it takes 4749620400 iterations to get a 0 (starting with the default seed).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If [this link](https://www.opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/Libc-1044.1.2/stdlib/FreeBSD/rand.c) is the definition of Mac OS X `rand()`, then 0 will never be produced. It's not a very good pseudo random number generator, IMHO.

Amongst its other flaws, its state is the previously returned value, which means that it is a strict function from previous value to next value; it's cycle cannot be larger than its range, which is `[1, RAND_MAX-1]`. (It cannot produce 0 because 0 is a fixed-point in the algorithm.)

Comment: I found this, discussing freebsd rand, which osx appears to use, it says 0 is never returned:  http://lists.freebsd.org/pipermail/svn-src-head/2013-July/049051.html

Comment: I can confirm by manual decompilation of `libSystem.B.dylib` on 10.6.8 that this is the implementation of `rand()`. It sucks; Use `random()`, which on BSD is based on `arc4random`. Alternately, use my PRNG for non-cryptographic purposes, [`xorshift128+`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xorshift#Xorshift.2B)

Comment: Hmmm, per [link](https://www.opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/Libc-1044.1.2/stdlib/FreeBSD/rand.c) it looks  like  `srand(2088216195) --> rand() == 0` when `#define USE_WEAK_SEEDING 1` and `srand(2147483647) --> rand() == 0` otherwise. So unclear on how 0 will never be produced.  (`RAND_MAX == 0x7FFFFFF`, 32-bit int)

Comment: @chux, I don't think `#define USE_WEAK_SEEDING 1` is the default build option. Or at least, it wasn't when this question was asked.

Comment: @chux: Yep, I guess if you chose to call `srand(RAND_MAX)`, you would get a zero as the next "random" number. But you would never get another one, because `if (*ctx == 0) *ctx = 123459876;`, and I doubt whether many people use that particular seed. If it weren't for that test, after that seed, `rand` would only produce zeros.

Comment: Note: 2 seeds `0xfffffffe, RAND_MAX` followed by `rand()` return 0.  Agree that after seeding and return of 0, a subsequent zero (and `RAND_MAX`) is not possible without another seed.  That `rand()` implementation has numerous weaknesses.

Comment: @chux: given the fact that it is common to combine a bad PRNG (`rand`) with a bad seed (`time(NULL)`), it seems like it will be a while before zero becomes a common result :-)

Comment: Indeed, perhaps [Jan 19, 2038](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem) or [2106](http://neilrieck.net/docs/calendar_time_y2k_etc.html#Y2038)?

Answer (score 2):

The standard requires that successive calls to `rand` form a sequence which is a subset of the space `[0; RAND_MAX]`. It doesn't require that all the possible values occur in any of the possible sequences.

So to answer your question: You aren't guaranteed to get a zero; It's up to the implementation (And judging from the other answers, BSD libc's implementation does indeed never return `0`).

[§7.22.2.2](http://www.iso-9899.info/n1570.html#FOOTNOTE.295)

> There are no guarantees as to the quality of the random sequence produced and some implementations are known to produce sequences with distressingly non-random low-order bits.

Comment: I don't see where the sequence is guaranteed to be a cycle.

Comment: @rici: The standard calls the result pseudo-random integers, which by definition are doomed to loop over, else they wouldn't have the pseudo- prefix.

Comment: As long as we're clear that the cycle does not have a restricted length (i.o.w., it is not a simple permutation of a subset of the range), I'll agree, based on the repeatability requirement in the description of `srand`. It's true (and unfortunate) that there are not even guidelines about the frequency of occurrence of possible values in the sequences.

Comment: @rici Well the cycle can't be longer than `pow(2, sizeof(unsigned)*CHAR_BIT)`, so the length is indeed restricted?

Comment: The internal state can be wider than unsigned. The number of possible sequences is restricted by the width of the seed, but their cycle length is only restricted by the width of the internal state, which is not specified.

Comment: @rici If that's the case, where did the extra entropy come from? The internal state can't be wider than `srand`'s argument or else repeatability isn't guaranteed.

Comment: There is no extra entropy, which is why the number of possible sequences is limited. But the length of the sequence's cycle is still only limited by length the internal state, even if much of the internal state is initialized to a fixed value (such as 0). IOW, if the prototype of `srand` were changed to accept a `char` (without changing the width of the actual seed), there would only be 256 possible sequences, but each sequence could still have a cycle length of 2^32 (if char and unsigned have 8 and 32 bits, respectively). So you could use the Mersenne Twister as a rand implementation.

Comment: @rici I see it now. Thanks for the correction! I changed it.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: what @rici said.

[It looks like the FreeBSD rand never returns 0](http://lists.freebsd.org/pipermail/svn-src-head/2013-July/049051.html)

That message chain has a patch, but it is not included in the apple open-source source.

<strike>It should eventually return zero, but on my computer, `RAND_MAX` is 2147483647</strike>

`printf("rand_max = %d\r\n", RAND_MAX);`

Wolfram alpha can't calculate that small of a probability.

Running these examples:

`prob x>0 for x binomial with n=100000 and p=.00001`

`prob x>0 for x binomial with n=10000 and p=.0001`

`prob x>0 for x binomial with n=1000 and p=.001`

Show that after for a probablity of 1/N, N attempts appears to approach about 0.63

It does look like 5*N attempts should get you over 99% though.

I don't know how long your computer will take to make 10 billion calls to rand though.

Comment: You're making the unfortunately unwarranted assumption that the output of `rand()` is a perfectly unbiased random stream. However, the algorithm used by Mac OS X is not perfectly unbiased, and it's not very random either.

Comment: @rici I was, and I looked at your link, and found a post about the freebsd rand never returning 0, the path to the apple doc mentions it, so I figure...