# Create a 128 byte random number

Tags: c, random

If the `rand()` function creates a random number that is 4 bytes in length, and I wanted to create a random number that is 1024 bits in length (128 bytes), is the easiest method to get this by concatenating the `rand()` function 256 times or is there an alternative method?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
  const char data[128];
  memset(&data, 0x36, 128);

  printf("%s\n", data);
  puts("");
  printf("%d\n", sizeof(data)/sizeof(data[0]));
  puts("");

  int i = 0;
  unsigned long rez = 0;

  for(i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
      unsigned int num = rand();
      rez = rez + num;
      printf("%x\n", rez);
  }

  printf("%x\n", rez);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes, it's the easiest way.

Comment: Why 256 times? 128 bytes / 4 bytes = 32

Comment: It's certainly the *easiest* way, once you get your math correct, as per @Gerhardh - you just have to investigate whether the distribution will be what you want. If it's a simple PRNG (for example, if it follows the `t(n) = t(n-1) * m + c modulo x` method), you may find some 128-bit values impossible.

Comment: More generally, "concatenation" means that you have to repeatedly multiply the currently accumulated value by `RAND_MAX + 1` and then add the next `rand()` result to the product. Repeat until you reach the desired length.

Comment: 1024 bits -> 128 bytes, unless my math is wrong. So although the data is not necessary a string, it can still be concatenated through `strcat` or must a new function be created to concatenate the data?

Comment: Notice that `rand()` generates random numbers between 0 and `RAND_MAX`, which often is way smaller than 2³²-1 (classic case: MSVC++); thus, it's incorrect to say that it generates a 4-byte random number.

Comment: Calling it 32 times would be enough (32 * 4 = 128).

Comment: `strcat` has noting to do with this. The best way to achieve that depends on several factors. Do you have support for 1024-bit arithmetics? Is your `rand()` really generating 4 bytes of random bits? Again, the most general way to "concatenate" the results is described in my comment above: use arithmetic, multiply and add repeatedly.

Comment: So kind of like the sample code that I've been working with (added it recently to the question). But that does not cause the value to extend beyond 4 bytes, so something must be wrong...

Comment: For what purpose do you need such a random number? Do you just want it displayed or is it something else?

Comment: The number is supposed to be stored in memory, and move around memory when interrupted by another peripheral (its an embedded project). The data value is supposed to serve as a key or password

Answer (score 4):

> is the easiest method to get this by concatenating the rand() function 256 times or is there an alternative method?

Each `rand()` returns a value in the `[0...RAND_MAX]` range.  `RAND_MAX` is limited to `32767 <= RAND_MAX <= INT_MAX`.

Very commonly `RAND_MAX` is a [Mersenne number](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MersenneNumber.html) of the form 2<sup>n</sup> − 1.  Code can take advantage of this this very common implementation dependent value.  Each `rand()` call then provides `RAND_MAX_BITS` and not 32 as suggested by OP for a 4-byte `int`. [@Matteo Italia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50819313/create-a-128-byte-random-number/50820616#comment88644503_50819313)

[See far below update]

```
#include <stdlib.h>

#if RAND_MAX == 0x7FFF
#define RAND_MAX_BITS 15
#elif RAND_MAX == 0x7FFFFFFF
#define RAND_MAX_BITS 31
#else
#error TBD code
#endif
```

Call `rand()` `⌈size * 8 / RAND_MAX_BITS⌉` times.  This eases the number of `rand()` calls needed from `size`.

```
void rand_byte(uint8_t *dest, size_t size) {
  int r_queue = 0;
  int r_bit_count = 0;
  for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    int r = 0;
    //printf("%3zu %2d %8x\n", i, r_bit_count, r_queue);
    if (r_bit_count < 8) {
      int need = 8 - r_bit_count;
      r = r_queue << need;
      r_queue = rand();
      r ^= r_queue;  // OK to flip bits already saved in `r`
      r_queue >>= need;
      r_bit_count = RAND_MAX_BITS - need;
    } else {
      r = r_queue;
      r_queue >>= 8;
      r_bit_count -= 8;
    }
    dest[i] = r;
  }
}

int main(void) {
  uint8_t buf[128];
  rand_byte(buf, sizeof buf);
  ...
  return 0;
}
```

If you want the easiest bit less efficient *code*, simply call  `rand()` for each byte as answered by [@dbush](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50820014/2410359)

---

[Update 2021]

[@Anonymous Question Guy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4589384/2410359) posted a nifty macro that returns the bit width of a [Mersenne number](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MersenneNumber.html), more generally than the `#if RAND_MAX == 0x7FFF` approach above.

```
/* Number of bits in inttype_MAX, or in any (1<<b)-1 where 0 <= b < 3E+10 */
#define IMAX_BITS(m) ((m) /((m)%0x3fffffffL+1) /0x3fffffffL %0x3fffffffL *30 \
              + (m)%0x3fffffffL /((m)%31+1)/31%31*5 + 4-12/((m)%31+3))

_Static_assert((RAND_MAX & 1 && (RAND_MAX/2 + 1) & (RAND_MAX/2)) == 0, 
    "RAND_MAX is not a Mersenne number");
#define RAND_MAX_BITS IMAX_BITS(RAND_MAX)
```

Comment: cool. Both that article and the Wikipedia article also mention that "Mersenne number" is often used only for numbers where the exponent is prime. But it is often used your way, too.

Comment: By the way, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29336510/) is probably relevant to your answer. The C standard only defines the range of possible values returned by `rand()`; it doesn't insist that all of them can be produced. So the OS X implementation cited is conformant.

Comment: @rici True that the _quality_ of functions like `rand()`, `sqrt()`, `pow()` and many others are not tightly specified by C:  [caveat emptor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caveat_emptor).

Comment: TBH instead of wasting time sniffing the properties of the builtin `rand()` (which is often sub-par) I'd just embed a good XorShift generator with a full 32 or 64 bit output, call it 4 or 2 times and be happy with it.

Comment: @MatteoItalia True and that idea would serve as a good answer by you.  As OP's question was about `rand()` usage (sometimes code requirements restrict options) - this answer details how to minimize calls about `rand()`.

Answer (score 3):

The C standard states that `RAND_MAX` has a minimum value of 32767 (0x7fff), so it's best to work under that assumption.

Because the function will only return 15 random bits, using all the bits in one call will involve some bit shifting and masking to get the results in the proper place.  The simplest way to do this would be to call `rand` 128 times, take the low order byte of each result, and write it to your byte array:

```
unsigned char rand_val[128];

for (int i=0; i<128; i++) {
    rand_val[i] = rand() & 0xff;
}
```

Don't forget to call `srand` exactly **once** somewhere before this in your code.

Using `strcat` as you mentioned in your comment won't work because this function works on null terminated strings, and a byte containing 0 is a valid random number.

If you plan on using these random values for anything involving cryptography, you're better off using a secure random number generator.  If you have OpenSSL available, use `RAND_bytes` for this purpose:

```
unsigned char rand_val[128];
RAND_bytes(rand_val, sizeof(rand_val));
```

Comment: I used a loop similar to the first snippet of code you provided, but is there a way of taking that entire array and saving it to a singular variable?

Comment: @nice_remark It depends on the type of the variable.

Answer (score 2):

On most POSIX (Unix-like) systems, you can also read 128 bytes from `/dev/urandom` which you would open like a regular file in binary mode — even though POSIX does not specify the device.

Comment: I don't believe Posix requires or even suggests `/dev/{,u}random`, although many popular unix-likes provide them. Posix requires `null`, `tty` and `console` in the `/dev/` namespace: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap10.html

Answer (score 0):

The properties of C `rand()` are vaguely specified by the standard; as said in a comment, the number of actual usable bits depends from implementation, and their quality has been historically plagued by sub-par implementations. Also, `rand()` affects the global state of the program *and* on many implementations is not thread safe.

Given that a there are good, known and simple PRNGs such as the ones from the XorShift family, I would just use one of them.

```
#include <stdint.h> 
/* The state must be seeded so that it is not all zero */
uint64_t s[2];
uint64_t xorshift128plus(void) {
    uint64_t x = s[0];
    uint64_t const y = s[1];
    s[0] = y;
    x ^= x << 23;
    s[1] = x ^ y ^ (x >> 17) ^ (y >> 26);
    return s[1] + y;
}

void next128bits(unsigned char ch[16]) {
    uint64_t t = xorshift128plus();
    memcpy(ch, &t, sizeof(t));
    t = xorshift128plus();
    memcpy(ch + 8, &t, sizeof(t));
}
```